# paypal-checkout-component for vue stays in sandbox mode

Tags: vue.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm struggling to go live. It's weird how something works in sandbox mode but then either there is no documented way to switch to production or it just does not work.

So here is what I got:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .paypal
    Spinner(:size="8" :thickness="3")
    PaypalButtons.buttons(
      :env="env"
      :style="style"
      :createOrder="order"
      :onInit="init"
      :onClick="validate"
      :onApprove="approve"
      :onError="error"
    )
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PayPal',
  props: {
    env: {
      type: String,
      default: 'sandbox',
      validator: value => ['sandbox', 'production'].includes(value)
    },
  },
  // ...
}
</script>
```

I've tried to set the `env` prop to `production` and removing it completely. I can not find any documentation on *how to set the environment*. I must miss something fundamental.

The error:

As I mentioned the sandbox mode works fine, but as soon as I go live (server side using PayPals production URL and client side with the corresponding env prop), I'm getting the following errors

**Request**

URL: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/graphql?UpdateClientConfig.

BODY:

```
{
  "query": "\n            mutation UpdateClientConfig(\n                $orderID : String!,\n                $fundingSource : ButtonFundingSourceType!,\n                $integrationArtifact : IntegrationArtifactType!,\n                $userExperienceFlow : UserExperienceFlowType!,\n                $productFlow : ProductFlowType!,\n                $buttonSessionID : String\n            ) {\n                updateClientConfig(\n                    token: $orderID,\n                    fundingSource: $fundingSource,\n                    integrationArtifact: $integrationArtifact,\n                    userExperienceFlow: $userExperienceFlow,\n                    productFlow: $productFlow,\n                    buttonSessionID: $buttonSessionID\n                )\n            }\n        ",
  "variables": {
    "orderID": "17884710UT885974F",
    "fundingSource": "paypal",
    "integrationArtifact": "PAYPAL_JS_SDK",
    "userExperienceFlow": "INCONTEXT",
    "productFlow": "SMART_PAYMENT_BUTTONS"
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "updateClientConfig": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "_name": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "checkpoints": [
                "patchClientConfig"
            ],
            "contingency": true,
            "data": {
                "message": "The specified resource does not exist."
            },
            "message": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
            "meta": {},
            "path": [
                "updateClientConfig"
            ],
            "statusCode": 200
        }
    ],
    "extensions": {
        "correlationId": "464b1d56d4581",
        "tracing": {
            "duration": 98157194,
            "endTime": "2021-09-06T16:29:45.133Z",
            "execution": {
                "resolvers": [
                    {
                        "duration": 96271082,
                        "fieldName": "updateClientConfig",
                        "parentType": "Mutation",
                        "path": [
                            "updateClientConfig"
                        ],
                        "returnType": "Boolean",
                        "startOffset": 1222180
                    }
                ]
            },
            "startTime": "2021-09-06T16:29:45.035Z",
            "version": 1
        }
    }
}
```

There is another request to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/graphql?GetCheckoutDetails with a similar response.

As far as I can tell the request URL should not be www.sandbox.paypal...

I have also [commented on an existing issue on GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1304#issuecomment-913551746), but I believe it will take too long to get an answer that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a sandbox client ID.

Change to a live client ID, from an app in the "Live" tab of [your Applications in developer.paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using the sandbox API credentials for production.

Comment: The JS SDK environment is determined based on the client ID it is loaded with, and not anything else.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. Then the env prop is misleading. However, I just created new API keys and tried them .. same result

Comment: Shoot. You're right. I missed the constant in the init script :(
Thank you.